# How to inject a singleton class into a webapplication builder?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have an interface that I'm using between a `UserStore` and the database of my users:

```cs
public interface IUserDB
{
  // simplified for brevity
  string? GetPasswordHash(string username);
}
```

And a singleton that implements this (for testing purposes):

```cs
public class FakeUserDB : IUserDB
{
  private static FakeUserDB instance;

  private FakeUserDB()
  {
  }

  public static FakeUserDB GetInstance()
  {
    if (instance == null) instance = new FakeUserDB();
    return instance;
  }

  public string? GetPasswordHash(string username)
  {
    return "idk something";
  }
}
```

Now I have a `UserStore` that communicates with this singleton, that is passed in via the constructor:

```cs
public class MyUserStore : IUserStore<MyUser>, IUserPasswordStore<MyUser>, IUserTwoFactorStore<MyUser>, 
  IUserLockoutStore<MyUser>, IUserRoleStore<MyUser>, IUserClaimStore<MyUser>
{
  private readonly string _connectionString;
  private readonly IUserDB _userDB;

  public MyUserStore(IConfiguration configuration, IUserDB db)
  {
      _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
      _userDB = db;
  }

  // A lot more stuff goes below here
  // ....
}
```

I'm aware that I need to add this as a dependency injection to my program.cs, but I'm not sure how to do so because `FakeUserDB` doesn't have a public constructor. When I try:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserDB, FakeUserDB>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserStore<MyUser>, MyUserStore>();
```

It doesn't work. Is there a way that I can add a singleton service to my builder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of implementing the class as a singleton, you can leave that to the IoC container:

```
public class FakeUserDB : IUserDB
{
  public FakeUserDB()
  {
  }

  public string? GetPasswordHash(string username)
  {
    return "idk something";
  }
}
```

In the IoC, you register it as a singleton:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserDB, FakeUserDB>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserStore<MyUser>, MyUserStore>();
```

As an alternative, if you do not want or cannot change the class, you can register the instance with a factory method like this:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserDB>(prov => FakeUserDB.GetInstance());
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserStore<MyUser>, MyUserStore>();
```